# Deactivate 'Nike+' exclusive features form AppleWatch 2 - Nike+ edition

Tags: apple-watch, customization, health.app

For whatever reason* you decide that you want your Apple Watch Nike Plus to function just like a standard Apple Watch:

- no more running notifications,
- no ugly watch faces,
- etc.

which are exclusive to the Nike Plus.

Is it possible to disable all NikePlus-exclusive features?

- you really liked the Nike Plus band and can't get it any other way,
- you broke your leg and no more running for you,
- some other excuse

Comment: You're naming almost all reasons why I would buy the nike+ version without the nike+ stuff =)

Answer (score 1):

Because the AppleWatch Nike+ edition isn't available yet this information is not available .. BUT I do can tell your able to turn off the notifications, just like the 'breath' / 'you need to stand for 1 minute' (while driving your car) notifications. You can change your watchfases to normal version but won't be able to remove the nike+ app from your watch as it's bound to the exclusive Watchface.